# riggify face rig makes the eyes so error

Tags: rigging

I use riggify to rig my character.
and his eyelids look so bad.
[image]
[image]

I used MAYA for years. There is a function on MAYA is I can choose an individual point to control its weight.
I don't know if blender has the same function.
or someone can help with riggify rigs?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

In edit mode you can select a vertex, in the "N" properties panel you will be able to read its weight values in the "vertex weights" tab. If more than one vertex is selected you can copy the values of the active (last selected) vertex to the others.

When I use Rigify face rig, I generally add a correction shape key in order to flatten the eyelids and the lips, using drivers to automate the shape keys effects.

Comment: Thank you very much~